# SQL ORACLE ERROR: ORA-00905 Missing Keyword

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using Oracle SQL Developer. Really new to SQL and not sure why I'm getting this error.

The error:

ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
*Cause:
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 128

```
SELECT r.ROOM_ID, w.HEAD_NURSE, w.WARD_NAME, p.LEAVING_DATE, count(CASE p.PATIENT_ID when to_date('2022-01-07', 'YYYY-MM-DD') < p.LEAVING_DATE then 1 else null END) AS No_Of_Patients_In_Room
FROM ROOM r, WARD w, PATIENT_DETAILS p
WHERE r.HEAD_NURSE = 'Some Nurses Name' AND w.WARD_NAME = 'Some Ward Name' AND p.ROOM_ID = r.ROOM_ID
group by r.ROOM_ID, w.HEAD_NURSE, w.WARD_NAME, p.LEAVING_DATE;
```

It should only count the PATIENT_ID when the LEAVING_DATE is after the date specified. I could just remove the data that has a LEAVING_DATE that has already gone past the date but I would still like to know what is causing this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `CASE` syntax has 2 forms.

Don't mix them.

> ```
> select n
> , case n
>   when 1 then 'A'
>   when 2 then 'B'
>   else 'C'
>   end as form1
> from (select 1 as n from dual) q
> ```
>
> ```
>  N | FORM1
> -: | :----
>  1 | A
> ```

> ```
> select n
> , case 
>   when n=1 then 'A'
>   when n>1 then 'B'
>   else 'C'
>   end as form2
> from (select 2 as n from dual) q
> ```
>
> ```
>  N | FORM2
> -: | :----
>  2 | B
> ```

> ```
> select n
> , case n
>   when n=1 then 'A'
>   when n>1 then 'B'
>   else 'C'
>   end as badmix
> from (select 3 as n from dual) q
> ```
>
> ```
> ORA-00905: missing keyword
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a121ce2bcf48a461bc7a81b3cb7889f7)*

So this is wrong:

```
CASE p.PATIENT_ID when to_date('2022-01-07', 'YYYY-MM-DD') < p.LEAVING_DATE then 1 else null END
```

Comment: Thanks I think I understand that, but not sure it makes it do what I need it too. Do you know how I could make it show all the ROOM_ID's in a specific WARD and all the PATIENT_ID'S that are in each room? The part that gets me confused is that there is old data in the tables so I need to make sure that the PATIENT_ID's that are in the rooms have a LEAVING_DATE that is after the current date.

Comment: Basically, I need to it to only count PATIENT_ID if the LEAVING_DATE is past the date specified I think.

Comment: So something like `COUNT(CASE WHEN p.LEAVING_DATE > SYSDATE THEN p.PATIENT_ID END)`

Comment: Thx for the rep. Btw, I should note something. If you want to count unique id's, then add a DISTINCT. `COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN p.LEAVING_DATE > SYSDATE THEN p.PATIENT_ID END)`